# How can str.translate from Python 2, only removing characters, be made to work in Python 3?

Tags: python

This is an assignment that needs to change the name of the file within a certain folder, however, it doesn't change the name after all. Can anyone help?

```
import os

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Downloads\prank")
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print("Current Working Directory is " +saved_path)
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Downloads\prank")
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))
    os.chdir(saved_path)

rename_files()
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Downloads\prank\rename_files.py", line 10, in <module>
    rename_files()
  File "C:\Users\Downloads\prank\rename_files.py", line 8, in rename_files
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, '0123456789'))
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

This code works in Python 2, but does not work in Python 3. How can it be made to work in Python 3.6, I only need to delete characters.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory.

Comment: `str.translate` in Python 3 accepts only one argument.

Comment: I am new to the python, can you be more specific? The code runs ok within python 2.7

Comment: Thank you, It works! I will study str.maketrans function a bit more!

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the Python 2 [`str.translate()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) with the [Python 3 version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) (which is really the same as `unicode.tranlate()` in Python 2).

You can use the [`str.maketrans()` static method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) to create a translation map; pass your string of digits to be removed in as the *third* argument to that function:

```
file_name.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '0123456789'))
```

Better still, store the result of `str.maketrans()` outside of the loop, and re-use it:

```
no_digits = str.maketrans('', '', '0123456789')

for file_name in file_list:
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(no_digits))
```